# fetch-mock: GLOBAL is not defined

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, es6-promise, jestjs

I'm using fetch-mock for writing unit test cases for functions which use `isomorphic-fetch`. Here is the sample test suite:

```
 import connect from '../../src/utils/connect';
 import fetchMock from 'fetch-mock';

 describe('Unit | Utils | connect function', () => {
  it('should make a request', (done) => {
     const urlToTest = 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users';
     fetchMock
      .mock(urlToTest, 200)
      .getMock();

    const response = connect(urlToTest);
    expect(response);
    done();
  });
});
```

When running the test cases, I get the error

> /my_app/app/node_modules/fetch-mock/src/server.js: GLOBAL is not defined

I'm not able to debug this issue. Can anyone please let me know what am I doing incorrectly. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jest, add `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile` section to package.json:

```
{
  ...
  "jest": {
    ...
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile.js"
  }
}
```

Add this line to `setupTestFrameworkScriptFile.js`:

```
global.GLOBAL = global;
```

Comment: It's not working. I added an entry for  'isomorphic-fetch' and ' fetch-mock' in unmockedModulePathPatterns and added the above constant in the TestFrameworkScriptFile. None of my test cases ran successfully :(